# array undeclared ,first used in the function error during dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c, arrays, scope, dynamic-memory-allocation

Here i am writing a program which will do two things

1.get a number between 0 to 102,separate them and store them in an array

2.print the array for each number

For that purpose i wrote an if-else block which will initialize an array each time exactly according to the size of the current integer value which is denoted by variable called `num`

Meaning that if i have a number of single digit it will create an array of one element,If number is two digit long it will create an array of two element.But whenever i run the code i get the error mentioned in question title.

What might be the reason for that and how to solve this issue?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>

int mirror(int num,int *arr,int i);

int main(){
   int num=0,range=1;

   while(num<102){
      if(num<(int)pow(10,range))
      {
          int *arr =(int *)malloc(range*sizeof(int));
      }else{
          range+=1;
          int *arr =(int *)malloc(range*sizeof(int));

      }
      int i = 0;
      mirror(num,arr,i);
      for(i=0;i<range;i++){
         printf("%d ",arr[i]);
      }
      printf("\n");
      num++;
   }
}

int mirror(int num,int *arr,int i){

    if(num == 0){
        return 0;
    }
    arr[i] = num%10;
    mirror(num/10,arr,++i);

}
```

Comment: `arr` is declared inside `if` or `else` blocks, and it'll not be accessible after the block has finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scope of pointer `arr` is only within the if-else block. So, it's not available outside of it.
Declare it outside the if-else block and you'll be able to use it as you have.

```
      int *arr;

      if(num<(int)pow(10,range))
      {
          arr = malloc(range*sizeof(int));
      }else{
          range += 1;
          arr = malloc(range*sizeof(int));

      }
```

Notice I have removed the cast of the malloc() return value. It's needless in C and error-prone. See: http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html

Answer (score 1):

Array is local variable in `if/else` statement. You should put declaration of array in outer block of `while` and assignment in conditional block.